# How does this 2D6 probability math make sense?

Tags: probability, dice, percentages, algorithmic-game-theory

I have a question about understanding the math to a previous question I had posed (answered successfully). Link at the bottom.

The question is how does it make sense that rolling a 2D6 Die consisting of 111 22 3 for sides has the math work out where the probability to roll TWO 1s is 25% chance and rolling a 1 and a 2 is 33% chance?  what is the math here for a laman?

It is also interesting to me that only when rolling 2 die is there a 50% chance of getting 2 circles.

Here is the link (https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/207875/using-anydice-com-to-calculate-non-traditional-dice-combinations/207898?noredirect=1#comment570131_207898)

ABOVE is the original question.  BELOW is more math about these dice.

I am not even sure if the below example is correct.  I am trying to figure it out as i post this.

[![Here is prob for different combinations.  1= circle 2 =triangle and 3- diamond on the die][1]][1]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ph2s7.png

Comment: "A 2D6 die?" Usually, "a" and "die" are singular, and 2D6 refers to two six-sided dice, but the lack of matching between these makes me wonder if you mean something else by 2D6. As a rule, don't write abbreviations here unless they are **very** common **mathematical terms.** 2D6 is not one of those.

Comment: Note that this dice gives probabilities $\frac{1}{2}$ for a one , $\frac{1}{3}$ for a two and $\frac{1}{6}$ for a three. So, it is easy to conclude that two ones have probability $\frac{1}{4}$ and first a one then a two has probability $\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{6}$. The same probability occurs for a two and then a one. Hope this was helpful.

Comment: You have to be more specific when you say laman[sic]. What is your math background? Can you write out all of the outcomes of the two dice and count the favorable outcomes? Do you understand why the chance of getting a $1$ on an individual throw of the die is $\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: "It is also interesting to me that only when rolling 2 die is there a 50% chance of getting 2 circles." This is wrong if both dices have $111223$ on their faces and $1$ is "circle". Do you mean something else here ?

Comment: The probability of getting at least two $1$s (i.e. circles) from $3$ dice throws is indeed $\frac12$.  Think of it as equivalent to tossing three fair coins: you either get at least two Heads or at least two Tails, and these have equally probability.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to understand this, create a table and count. But the key is, the table has to have all the options equally likely. Just creating a table of $1,2,3$ is not going to work because $1$ has a different probability than $2$, or $2$ from $3$. But each side of the die is equally likely, so your table needs entries for each of the sides:

$$\begin{array}{c|cccccc}
&1&1&1&2&2&3\\\hline
1&\color{red}{1,1}&\color{red}{1,1}&\color{red}{1,1}&\color{blue}{1,2}&\color{blue}{1,2}&1,3\\
1&\color{red}{1,1}&\color{red}{1,1}&\color{red}{1,1}&\color{blue}{1,2}&\color{blue}{1,2}&1,3\\
1&\color{red}{1,1}&\color{red}{1,1}&\color{red}{1,1}&\color{blue}{1,2}&\color{blue}{1,2}&1,3\\
2&\color{blue}{2,1}&\color{blue}{2,1}&\color{blue}{2,1}&2,2&2,2&2,3\\
2&\color{blue}{2,1}&\color{blue}{2,1}&\color{blue}{2,1}&2,2&2,2&2,3\\
3&3,1&3,1&3,1&3,2&3,2&3,3
\end{array}$$

There are $36$ possibilities total, and each are equally likely to appear. Note that $9$ entries are $1,1$, so the probability of two $1$s is $\frac 9{36} = \frac 14 = 25\%$

There are six entries of $1,2$ and six entries of $2,1$, for a total of 12 entries that have a $1$ and a $2$. Thus the probability is $\frac{12}{36} = \frac 13 = 33.\overline 3\%$.

You don't explain anything about "circles" and I am not going to search through posts in hopes of figuring out what you cannot be bothered to post clearly.